# Resizing image to fit in a 320x320 imageview without loosing the quality and stretching

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, resize

i am trying to resize the image in a 320x320 imageview. i am capturing the image from camera and loading from gallery also. i am using the above code to resize;

```
-(UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image max:(int)kMaxResolution
{
  //  NSLog(@"W=%f h=%f",self.m_initialImage.size.width,self.m_initialImage.size.height);
   // int kMaxResolution = 430;
    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

//    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
//    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//    NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width, image.size.height);
//    float ratioWidth=image.size.width/380;
//    float imgWidth=image.size.width/ratioWidth;
//    float tmp=image.size.height/568;
//    float imgHeight=image.size.height/tmp;
    if(image.size.width<image.size.height)
    {
    normalizedImage=[self compressMe:normalizedImage width:320 height:500];
    }
        else
        {
           // normalizedImage=[self compressMe:normalizedImage width:380 height:380];
            normalizedImage=[self compressMe:normalizedImage width:340 height:320];
        }

    // Resize image
//    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 426));
//    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 426)];
//    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//    
//    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 320);
//    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
//    
//   UIImage *normalizedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
//    
//    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return normalizedImage;

}

-(UIImage*)compressMe:(UIImage*)image width:(float)width height:(float)height
{

    NSLog(@"%f,%f",width,height);
    // Get size of current image
    CGSize size = [image size];
    if( size.width == width
       && size.height == height){
        return image;
    }

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    double ratio;
    double delta;
    CGPoint offset;

    //make a new square size, that is the resized imaged width
    CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.height);

    //figure out if the picture is landscape or portrait, then
    //calculate scale factor and offset
    if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
        ratio = newSize.height / image.size.height;
        delta = ratio*(image.size.width - image.size.height);
        offset = CGPointMake(delta/2, 0);
        sz.width=ratio*image.size.width;
    } else {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width;
        delta = ratio*(image.size.height - image.size.width);
        offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2);
    }
    NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f",offset.x,offset.y,ratio * image.size.height,(ratio * image.size.width));
    //make the final clipping rect based on the calculated values
   // CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,
           //                      (ratio * image.size.width-((offset.y)+offset.x)),
            //                     ((ratio * image.size.height)-(offset.y)*2));
    CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(0,0,
                                 (ratio * image.size.width),
                                 (ratio * image.size.height));

   // CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);

    CGSize szz = CGSizeMake((ratio * image.size.width),
                            (ratio * image.size.height));

    //start a new context, with scale factor 0.0 so retina displays get
    //high quality image
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(szz, YES, 0.0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(szz);
    }
    UIRectClip(clipRect);
    [image drawInRect:clipRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",newImage.size.width,newImage.size.height);
    return newImage;
}
```

The image is not getting resized properly, can anyone suggest me where i am lacking behind.

Thanks

Comment: What will be the size of Captured image..?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't read the whole code.

But since you are trying to put the image in an UIImageView, Why don't you use "contentMode" property to let the UIImageView resize the image appropriately to fit the image view